# Blazor data binding two values to selectlist

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I can easily bind one value to my model, but what if I want to bind two or more?

Sample code, tried to bind to the complex object but it fails.

Component:

```
 <select id="myClassId" @onchange="SelectionChanged" class="form-control">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            @foreach (var myObject in myClassList)
                            {
                                <option value="@myObject">@myObject.AccountName</option>
                            }
                        </select>
```

Code

```
 void SelectionChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(((MyClass)e.Value).AccountId);
        Console.WriteLine(((MyClass)e.Value).AccountName);

    }
```

UPDATE:

Ended up doing this. Probably not the most elegant solution, but I'm not sure if there are other more "supported" ways.

```
<select id="myClassId" @onchange="SelectionChanged" class="form-control">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            @foreach (var myObject in myClassList)
                            {
                                <option value="@myObject.AccountId;@myObject.AccountName">@myObject.AccountName</option>
                            }
                        </select>
```

```
 void SelectionChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var accountId = e.Value.ToString().Split(";")[0];
        var accountName = e.Value.ToString().Split(";")[1];
        Console.WriteLine(accountId);
        Console.WriteLine(accountName);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The value of a select is a string. That is a fundamental limitation of the HTML, and has nothing to do with Blazor. You cannot use an object. Your best bet here is to assign an id or some other uniquely identifying value, and then in your onchange handler, look up the actual object you want to assign using that value.

Comment: Ok thanks, I could use the id but how do I retrieve that from the event? There only seems to be a e.Value on it

Comment: I made it work in other ways. Check update on my post. As said, not sure if it's the most elegant way though.